# Do Grays exist in Star Trek?

Tags: star-trek, aliens

Do the gray aliens (a.k.a. Grays) reported in alien abduction accounts exist in Star Trek? If so, has it been mentioned in Star Trek canon that these are the same aliens that [people have reportedly encountered](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barney_and_Betty_Hill)?

Comment: Do the weirdo's who abducted Riker and removed his arm count?  That was pretty much the cliche modern "alien abduction" story, up to the crew members being hypnotized to remember their experiences.

Comment: @rld - From the episode [Schisms](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Schisms_(episode)), correct? I would count it.

Comment: The [Gorn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:StarTrek-Gorn.jpg) are fairly gray.  I wouldn't call one bug-eyed (to its face).

Comment: Huumons. Are red-tinted gray.  The red tint is more obvious in the lighter ones.

Comment: Do Andorians count? Some of them are so greyish it's more grey (or white even) than blue.

Comment: If you're simply looking for Roswell-like aliens in SciFi, you may be more interested in [aliens like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FgNnQ.gif). Asgard, from Stargate.

Comment: The Bynars from the ST:TNG 1x15 episode "11001001" resembled greys and had a hive-like culture, although they didn't abduct humans.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The closest visually would probably be

## Barash

[image]

An alien who abducted / held Riker in TNG:S4:8 episode "[Future Imperfect](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Future_Imperfect_(episode))"

Answer (score 21):

Possibly, but we don't see them in the show.
The only mention of any race of alien that "abducts" humans is in the Voyager Episode "The 37s", where we learn that a race in the Delta Quadrant, the Briori, frequently kidnapped humans to be kept as slaves. However, the human's revolted and drove the Briori off long ago, and we never get a chance to see what one might look like.

Possibly related to the question is the Deep Space 9 episode, "Little Green Men", where we learn that Quark, Rom, and Nog get sucked back in time and are inadvertently, responsible for the Roswell incident.

Comment: I remembered *Little Green Men* while writing my question. It's possible the army guys/lady probably thought these aliens were the ones responsible for the abductions.

Comment: Not especially relevant to the OP, but 'The only mention of any race of alien that "abducts" humans is in the Voyager Episode "The 37s"' isn't true. TNG episodes Schisms and Allegiance are both about crew members being abducted.

Comment: The Briori weren't the only race that abducted humans. The Skagarans referenced in the ST: Enterprise episode "North Star" did so as well

Answer (score 14):

[image: Corbomitian Guy]

I know this alien was a ruse, but there must be some veracity to it, since Kirk and crew accept it so readily.  It doesn't seem reasonable that Balok would have chosen a completely fantasy disguise to try and fool rational adults, I would assume these dudes exist in-universe.

(He is an avatar used by a character Balok in the episode "The Corbomite Maneuver", and also appears in the end credit sequence of every episode)

Comment: I remember seeing this alien during the credits, freaked me out. +1.

Comment: The Enterprise's stated mission was to "boldly go where no man had gone before."  It stands to reason they'd be expecting to see alien species no one had ever seen before.  Therefore, not too surprising that a "completely fantasy disguise" might fool rational adults after all.

Comment: Kirk and crew accepted most aliens pretty readily. In my recollection, the only one they found surprising was the Horta -- the organization that started mining the planet didn't realize it was inhabited because the lifesign detectors didn't detect silicon-based life.

Comment: I'm suggesting that "greys" are sort of a galactic scarecrow.  I believe Balok took a form that he had reason to believe would frighten humanoids, not pique their curiosity.  Not every space faring humanoid would prove as brave as Kirk and crew did.  If one wanted to try and scare away curious mice, one might dress as a cat.

Answer (score 12):

Interdimensional aliens that abduct crew members from the Enterprise do exist. They are seen in the episode "Schisms".  It is not established that these are in fact the same grey aliens reported in earth's history, but their behavior of abduction, experimentation, and return are similar.

[Schisms (Episode)](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Schisms_(episode))

However, they do not physically resemble descriptions of greys.

[image: One of the solanogen-based lifeforms]

Comment: "descriptions of greys" would most likely be the helmets of these guys...

Answer (score 4):

We know that the aliens recovered from the crash at Roswell, New Mexico in 1947 were [ferengi](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Little_Green_Men_(episode)); as this is one of the roots of the grey alien myth (along with Betty and Barney Hill), I'm inclined to say that grey aliens are generally other species that have been (deliberately?) misidentified.

Comment: That certainly explains why the world ended up as it is from a financial perspective.